# np.mean() vs np.average() in Python NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, average, mean

I notice that

```
In [30]: np.mean([1, 2, 3])
Out[30]: 2.0

In [31]: np.average([1, 2, 3])
Out[31]: 2.0
```

However, there should be some differences, since after all they are two different functions.

**What are the differences between them?**

Comment: Actually, the documentation doesn't make it immediately clear, as far as I can see. Not saying it is impossible to tell, but I think this question is valid for Stack Overflow all the same.

Comment: numpy.mean : Returns the average of the array elements.

Comment: @joaquin: "Compute the arithmetic mean along the specified axis." vs "Compute the weighted average along the specified axis."?

Comment: @Blender right. I was just trying to make a kind of funny response to your comment because if I follow your instructions the first thing I read in the [docs for numpy.mean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) is *numpy.mean : Returns the average of the array elements* which is funny if you are looking for the answer to the OP question.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

np.average takes an optional weight parameter.  If it is not supplied they are equivalent.  Take a look at the source code: [Mean](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py), [Average](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py)

np.mean:

```
try:
    mean = a.mean
except AttributeError:
    return _wrapit(a, 'mean', axis, dtype, out)
return mean(axis, dtype, out)
```

np.average:

```
...
if weights is None :
    avg = a.mean(axis)
    scl = avg.dtype.type(a.size/avg.size)
else:
    #code that does weighted mean here

if returned: #returned is another optional argument
    scl = np.multiply(avg, 0) + scl
    return avg, scl
else:
    return avg
...
```

Comment: Why do they offer two different functions? Seems they should just offer `np.average` since `weights` is already optional. Seems unnecessary and only serves to confuse users.

Comment: @Geoff I would rather have them throw a NotImplementedException for "average", to educate users that the arithmetic mean is not identical to "the average".

Comment: @Geoff [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38271426/7009806) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897092/7009806) answers actually tell you why there is a need for these two functions.

Answer (score 48):

`np.mean` always computes an arithmetic mean, and has some additional options for input and output (e.g. what datatypes to use, where to place the result).

`np.average` can compute a weighted average if the `weights` parameter is supplied.

Answer (score 33):

**In some version of numpy** there is another imporant difference that you must be aware:

`average` do not take in account masks, so compute the average over the whole set of data.

`mean` takes in account masks, so compute the mean only over unmasked values.

```
g = [1,2,3,55,66,77]
f = np.ma.masked_greater(g,5)

np.average(f)
Out: 34.0

np.mean(f)
Out: 2.0
```

Comment: Note: `np.ma.average` works.  Also, there is a [bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7330).

Comment: `np.average` and `np.mean` both takes into account masks. I've tried and got the value of "Out: `2.0`"

Comment: @CEB the new version probably fix the bug thanks for reporting

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the differences already noted, there's another extremely important difference that I just now discovered the hard way:  unlike `np.mean`, `np.average` doesn't allow the `dtype` keyword, which is essential for getting correct results in some cases.  I have a very large single-precision array that is accessed from an `h5` file.  If I take the mean along axes 0 and 1, I get wildly incorrect results unless I specify `dtype='float64'`:

```
>T.shape
(4096, 4096, 720)
>T.dtype
dtype('<f4')

m1 = np.average(T, axis=(0,1))                #  garbage
m2 = np.mean(T, axis=(0,1))                   #  the same garbage
m3 = np.mean(T, axis=(0,1), dtype='float64')  # correct results
```

Unfortunately, unless you know what to look for, you can't necessarily tell your results are wrong.  I will never use `np.average` again for this reason but will always use `np.mean(.., dtype='float64')` on any large array.  If I want a weighted average, I'll compute it explicitly using the product of the weight vector and the target array and then either `np.sum` or `np.mean`, as appropriate (with appropriate precision as well).

Comment: Very surprising. Do you know why this happens, and can you file a bug report? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your invocation, the two functions are the same.

`average` can compute a weighted average though.

Doc links: [`mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [`average`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html)