# What is the meaning of 'mean_test_score' in cv_result?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

Hello I'm doing a GridSearchCV and I'm printing the result with the `.cv_results_` function from `scikit learn`.

My problem is that when I'm evaluating by hand the mean on all the test score splits I obtain a different number compared to what it is written in `'mean_test_score'`. Which is different from the standard `np.mean()`?

I attach here the code with the result:

```
n_estimators = [100]
max_depth = [3]
learning_rate = [0.1]

param_grid = dict(max_depth=max_depth, n_estimators=n_estimators, learning_rate=learning_rate)

gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=7)


grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, scoring=score_auc, cv=gkf)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X, Y, groups=patients)

grid_result.cv_results_
```

The result of this operation is:

```
{'mean_fit_time': array([ 8.92773601]),
 'mean_score_time': array([ 0.04288721]),
 'mean_test_score': array([ 0.83490629]),
 'mean_train_score': array([ 0.95167036]),
 'param_learning_rate': masked_array(data = [0.1],
              mask = [False],
        fill_value = ?),
 'param_max_depth': masked_array(data = [3],
              mask = [False],
        fill_value = ?),
 'param_n_estimators': masked_array(data = [100],
              mask = [False],
        fill_value = ?),
 'params': ({'learning_rate': 0.1, 'max_depth': 3, 'n_estimators': 100},),
 'rank_test_score': array([1]),
 'split0_test_score': array([ 0.74821666]),
 'split0_train_score': array([ 0.97564995]),
 'split1_test_score': array([ 0.80089016]),
 'split1_train_score': array([ 0.95361201]),
 'split2_test_score': array([ 0.92876979]),
 'split2_train_score': array([ 0.93935856]),
 'split3_test_score': array([ 0.95540287]),
 'split3_train_score': array([ 0.94718634]),
 'split4_test_score': array([ 0.89083901]),
 'split4_train_score': array([ 0.94787374]),
 'split5_test_score': array([ 0.90926355]),
 'split5_train_score': array([ 0.94829775]),
 'split6_test_score': array([ 0.82520379]),
 'split6_train_score': array([ 0.94971417]),
 'std_fit_time': array([ 1.79167576]),
 'std_score_time': array([ 0.02970254]),
 'std_test_score': array([ 0.0809713]),
 'std_train_score': array([ 0.0105566])}
```

As you can see, doing the `np.mean` of all the test_score it gives you a value approximately of 0.8655122606479532 while the 'mean_test_score' is 0.83490629

Thanks for you help,
Leonardo.

Comment: Isn't the array with all the 'split0_test_score' , 'split1_test_score'.. and so on?

Comment: I am guessing`scoring=score_auc` is a custom scoring function you provide since it is not one of the allowed values. Is it weighted?

Comment: It's the sample score_auc evaluation


def score_auc(estimator, X, y):
    probas = estimator.predict_proba(X)
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y, probas[:, 0], pos_label=1)
    return auc(fpr, tpr)

Comment: Can you print the size of the folds? Run `print([(len(train), len(test)) for train, test in gkf.split(X, groups=patients)])`

Comment: Yes of course!
[(41835, 24377), (56229, 9983), (56581, 9631), (58759, 7453), (60893, 5319), (60919, 5293), (62056, 4156)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will post this as a new answer since its so much code:

The test and train scores of the folds are: (taken from the results you posted in your question)

```
test_scores = [0.74821666,0.80089016,0.92876979,0.95540287,0.89083901,0.90926355,0.82520379]
train_scores = [0.97564995,0.95361201,0.93935856,0.94718634,0.94787374,0.94829775,0.94971417]
```

The amount of training samples in those folds are: (taken from the output of `print([(len(train), len(test)) for train, test in gkf.split(X, groups=patients)])`)

```
train_len = [41835, 56229, 56581, 58759, 60893, 60919, 62056]
test_len = [24377, 9983, 9631, 7453, 5319, 5293, 4156]
```

Then the test- and train-means with the amount of training samples per fold as weight is:

```
train_avg = np.average(train_scores, weights=train_len)
-> 0.95064898361714389
test_avg = np.average(test_scores, weights=test_len)
-> 0.83490628649308296
```

So this is exactly the value sklearn gives you. It is also the correct mean accuracy of your classification. The mean of the folds is incorrect in that it depends on the somewhat arbitrary splits/folds you chose.

So in concusion, both explanations were indeed identical and correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you see the original code of `GridSearchCV` in their github repository, they dont use `np.mean()` instead they use `np.average()` with weights. Hence the difference. Here's their code:

```
n_splits = 3
test_sample_counts = np.array(test_sample_counts[:n_splits],
                                    dtype=np.int)
weights = test_sample_counts if self.iid else None
means = np.average(test_scores, axis=1, weights=weights)
stds = np.sqrt(np.average((test_scores - means[:, np.newaxis]) 
                               axis=1, weights=weights))

 cv_results = dict()
 for split_i in range(n_splits):
        cv_results["split%d_test_score" % split_i] = test_scores[:,
                                                              split_i]
 cv_results["mean_test_score"] = means        
 cv_results["std_test_score"] = stds
```

In case you want to know more about the difference between them take a look 
[Difference between np.mean() and np.average()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054243/np-mean-vs-np-average-in-python-numpy)

Comment: Indeed, but `np.average` and `np.mean` in the provided example give the same resilts.

Comment: They use weights parameter.

Comment: Yeap that would be the difference here.

Comment: As far as I understand the weight parameter is the sample count in the particular fold/split. So I guess this comes down t the same explanation as my answer?

Comment: @Johannes  I believe that's the case! +1 to your answer too. Both answers actually contribute to this question for different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the reason for the different means are different weighting factors in the mean calculation.

The `mean_test_score` that sklearn returns is the mean calculated on all samples where each sample has the same weight.

If you calculate the mean by taking the mean of the folds (splits), then you only get the same results if the folds are all of equal size. If they are not, then all samples of larger folds will automatically have a smaller impact on the mean of the folds than smaller folds, and the other way around.

Small numeric example:

```
mean([2,3,5,8,9]) = 5.4 # mean over all samples ('mean_test_score')

mean([2,3,5]) = 3.333 # mean of fold 1
mean([8,9]) = 8.5 # mean of fold 2

mean(3.333, 8.5) = 5.91 # mean of means of folds

5.4 != 5.91
```