# What is Mean_test_score and STD_Test_Score used for

Tags: scikit-learn

I just can't understand what is the difference between MeanTestScores and STDTestScores and how can we use them .

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :) I'm not at all familiar with SKlearn, but is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44947574/4051181) helpful? I don't know enough to tell if it's a similar question. If not, you might find it helpful to see how that question was asked - they included their code to help people understand what they're trying to do. You might also find it helpful to read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `javascript` or `jupyter-notebook`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).