# Matplotlib 3d surface plot showing values outside of axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

In matplotlib 3d-plotting `plot_surface` even when the x, y and z axis limits are set to be >=0 the negative z-portion of the surface is still getting plotted. The same does not happen for 2d plots- if out of 20 data points provided as input for plotting, 10 fall outside the axis limits, say first-quadrant, they simply do not get displayed in the plot.

Please see the below code and corresponding plot as an evidence (code run in Jupyter notebook) -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib import cm
%matplotlib notebook

x = np.linspace(0,1.5,100)
y = np.linspace(0,1.5,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = 1-X-Y
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_xlim(0,1.5)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.5)
ax.set_zlim(0,3)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
fig.savefig('Question10Fig')
```

[image: Above plot]

The existence of the blue colour along with the colour-bar alongside makes it evident that z<0 values are present in the plot. Why is that so?

Comment: This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to origin from

```py
ax.set_zlim(0,3)
```

Removing this line, the figure looks good to me. That seems to be a problem in matplotlib (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411587/matplotlib-3d-plot-how-to-use-set-zlim-correctly)).

Comment: thanks for sharing the reference post. It gave me the idea to use masking and thereby figure out a possible issue with mplot3d/matplotlib. The issue is that scatter plot respects masking while surface plots don't. I am explaining it in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67519618/matplotlib-mplot3d-scatterplot-respects-masking-but-surfaceplot-does-not-why).

As for the point of removing the line `ax.set_zlim(0,3)` , it does not the solve the aim of not plotting portions outside of first-quadrant. It just stops the anomaly from being manifested.

Comment: @AnirbanChakraborty: Of course, removing `ax.set_zlim` does not solve your problem, but it seems to be the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code:

```
z[z < 0] = np.nan
```

just using `set_zlim` is not enough.