# Why does np.ma.array take an inverted mask?

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I have some array

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

and some mask

```
mask = np.ones(a.shape, dtype=bool)
```

and can do

```
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(a[mask], a)  # True
```

---

However,

```
np.ma.array(a, mask)
```

is equivalent to

```
a[np.logical_not(mask)]
```

and

```
np.ma.array(a, np.logical_not(mask))
```

is equivalent to

```
a[mask]
```

---

**This seems counter intuitive to me.**

Would love an explanation for this design choice by numpy.

Comment: Your mask is an array of integers though, not booleans

Comment: @yatu thanks, fixed. Feel free to edit inaccuracies :) i hope the question itself is clear.

Comment: Interesting question, but I feel like that's quite literally the definition of a masked array. ["Masked values of True exclude the corresponding element from any computation."](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.array.html). Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987642/why-are-numpy-masked-arrays-useful) resolves it?

Comment: Are you asking why the code works the way it does (given how it's documented), or why the developers chose this particular convention (in contrast to what your intuition says it should be)?

Comment: @hpauli i actually don't understand the difference in what you stated. I asked why np.ma uses a different convention than np. My intuition is that they should be the same, i don't mind which way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [6]: a = np.array([1,2,3])                                                            
In [7]: idx = np.array([1,0,1], bool)                                                    
In [8]: idx                                                                              
Out[8]: array([ True, False,  True])
In [9]: a[idx]                                                                           
Out[9]: array([1, 3])
```

Just because you called a boolean array `mask`, does not mean it behaves as 'mask' in every sense of the word.  I intentionally choose a different name.  Yes, we do often call such an array `mask` and talk of 'masking', but what we are really doing is 'selecting'.  The `a[idx]` operations returns the elements of `a` where the `idx` is True.  It's the same as indexing with the `nonzero` tuple:

```
In [13]: np.nonzero(idx)                                                                 
Out[13]: (array([0, 2]),)
```

In `np.ma` mask is used in the sense of 'mask out', covering over.

```
In [10]: mm = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=idx)                                            
In [11]: mm                                                                              
Out[11]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 2, --],
             mask=[ True, False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
In [12]: mm.compressed()                                                                 
Out[12]: array([2])
```

In the display the masked values show up as '--'.  As the `np.ma` docs say, those elements a considered to be invalid, and will be excluded from computations.

`mm.filled` returns an array with the 'masked' value replaced by the 'fill':

```
In [16]: mm.filled()                                                                     
Out[16]: array([999999,      2, 999999])
```

we can do the same thing with `idx`:

```
In [17]: a[idx] = 999999                                                                 
In [18]: a                                                                               
Out[18]: array([999999,      2, 999999])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I asked *why* the different standard for np and np.ma, i understand the differences you specified here.

Comment: Doesn't really matter what I call the array with which i access the data array, i would expect it to behave the same, and it doesn't. I see that the docs specify the behavior, and i understand the behavior. I do not understand the logic that led to the choosing of the mask indicating "what not to select", as opposed to the numpy standard which is "what to select"

Comment: What I'm trying explain is that the two uses of a boolean array are unrelated.  Selecting and masking are different tasks, and don't have to follow the same logic.

Comment: Allright, is there an efficient way without applying `np.logical_not` or `~` to get a masked array from the already existing (inverted) mask? Without traversing the entire mask for negation first?

Comment: Why are you afraid of a simple `~`?  Don't use `np.ma` if you are seeking efficiency; it's a convenience class, not a performance one.  I don't think it has any custom c code; it's all Python.